# how to disable a chrome extension from running every time chrome restarts?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made an extension that just saves the url when clicked on it's button in the tool bar. But however the extension runs everytime when chrome restarts and thus saves the blank url. {p.s - it doesn't run for every new tab, just for a complete restart of chrome}.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without the source code, it's difficult to find a solution. Please edit your question to include the relevant source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to disable the extension when Chrome starts, I suggest you simply inspect the tab's href property and skip the new tab page. You may also want to skip other pages like the extension page or the history page. For example, the code below cycles through all the currently open tabs, but skips the new tab page:

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        if (tabs[i].href !== 'chrome://newtab/') {
            // Do stuff!
        }

    }
});
```

If you wanted to, you could even exclude all URLs that begin with "chrome://" using a regular expression or a substring like "tabs[i].indexOf('chrome://') === -1" (meaning the URL does not contain the string 'chrome://').

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if it's the first time your extension is running or it's just the browser starting up. I'd recommend you to use [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to store this kind data.

Here's a example:

*background.js*

```
if(localStorage["firstSetupDone"] == "true")
{
  /*Initialize my extension here*/
}
else
{
  /*Setup my extension then initialize it here*/
  localStorage["firstSetupDone"] = "true";
}
```